# Internal Server Error in Asp.net MVC and NodeJS API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

INTERNAL SERVER ERRRO IN ASP.NET MVC | Im using API Nodejs API

I'm getting this error :

{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:43:08 GMT
ETag: W/"207-dot71BoPtBULXh2HngHqO05/OVY"
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 519
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}

[image]

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "users/registration", content).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: It's "Internal Server Error (500)" without information. Maybe you can found more information on the server.

Comment: it's local server from nodejs api

Comment: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Connection: keep-alive
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5
  Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 14:32:45 GMT
  ETag: W/"21-HX68YSH75ZGzbDhFfNzzPWADJ2o"
  X-Powered-By: Express
  Content-Length: 33
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}

Getting This Error NOW

Comment: I don't know nodejs, but I think you can see the error detail in the nodejs console.

Comment: In the debug mode, try to set a break point in the `users/registration` method, check whether this method is called, and then step by step to debug your code. You could also use Logging in the `users/registration` method and catch the exception.

Comment: Besides, whether your application is a traditional Asp.net MVC application or Asp.net Core MVC application?

Comment: Asp.net MVC application